# BASH script 'sleep' command not working

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, automation, xdotool

I have written a script to work as an auto-clicker on my Ubuntu distribution. The clicking works, but the 'sleep' command doesn't seem to be working correctly. If I take out the click and run it from terminal then the sleeps work as intended. But when I bind it to a shortcut and run it while playing a game it doesn't sleep it seems it just keeps clicking.

```
 #!/bin/bash
counter=0     #number of iterations executed
loop_to=1800  #number of iterations to do
break_interval=10 #time to break, in seconds
click_interval=.5 #time between iterations, in seconds
break_at=15   #how many iterations before taking a break


while [ $counter -lt $loop_to ]; do
    xdotool click 1
    sleep $click_interval
    echo $counter
    let counter=counter+1
    if [[ $(( $counter % $break_at )) == 0 ]]; then   
        sleep $break_interval
        echo I slept
    fi
done
```

The most important sleep is the break_interval one because that is to pause the autoclicker for x amount of time.

Comment: Are you sure the script is run by `bash` when you run it via a shortcut? `[[` is the only thing that relies on `bash`.

Comment: You appear to have whitespace before the `#!` on the first line.  That would mean that the script does not necessarily run under `bash` (it depends which program launches it).

Comment: It was not being run using bash. For multiple reasons I believe, I didn't have access to the binding, just the script I wrote for my friend. He was running it using "sh" and so the BASH specific stuff was causing it to not work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test:

`[[ $(( $counter % $break_at )) == 0 ]]`

could be written:

`[ $(( $counter % $break_at )) -eq 0 ]`

`[[ x == y ]]` is bash-specific and tests for string equality.

`[ x -eq y ]` works with any POSIX shell and tests for integer equality.

As @cdarke notes, your shebang line is incorrect, the 1st two characters must be `#!`, and so you're probably getting `/bin/sh` to run this.

Comment: I posted this on behalf of a friend. Turns out he was running it with "sh", after some help and the suggestions in comments I got him there. Thanks guys!